# uptodate News Line in ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, ajax

Hiiiiii
I want to show a news line in my asp.net page
this line should revolve and it must be uptodate
without using refresh button (with AJAX)
this news line will takes the data
from the database...
I have tried with marquee tags but it didn't work well
any suggestion please

Comment: are you talking about a ticker-type object? also, post your code so we can attempt to help you...

Comment: yes I am talking about the ticker ..but is there any ready component
in the asp.net to achieve that...
my code depend on a normal label
and through the C# code I get the info from DB
and then but my news inside Marquee tag(to revolve)
and then assign the whole string to the label
with Ajax I am trying to do the same process
but the news line stops revolving when the Timer of Ajax is running
I hope it's clear to you ...

Answer (score 2):

Probably one of the easiest things you can do is to use the UpdatePanel within ASP.NET and use a ticker event that will PostBack to the server and refresh the content of your UpdatePanel given a specified interval time.

You can then tap into the client side AsynPostBack events to use a little bit of jQuery magic on the data to make it look good.  Either way, you'll end up with some serverside and client side code here.  You can code the client side in 100% JavaScript, but utilizing the jQuery framework would be very beneficial.

Here is a code sample on using the [jQuery Cycle](http://malsup.com/jquery/cycle/) plugin:

```
 <div id="product_ticker">
    <div>
        News A
    </div>
    <div>
        News B
    </div>
    <div>
        News C
    </div>
    <div>
        News D
    </div>
 </div>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('#product_ticker').cycle();
    });
</script>
```

Here are a couple of links worth looking at for more ideas:
* http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/build-a-simple-jquery-news-ticker/
* http://israelwebdev.wordpress.com/2009/03/25/jquery-ltrrtl-news-ticker/
* http://malsup.com/jquery/cycle/